# Cakephp, Where is the find converted into a mySql query?

Tags: cakephp

Where in the [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/) library is a find, with all its conditions, converted into a SQL query? I'm using MySQL, and not looking for `$this->element('sql_dump');` as an answer.

Comment: have you tried debugging the calls?

Comment: I finally found it, its in \lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php in the function read =)

Comment: The three people voting to close this question are obviously blind. The question is to the point, OP is looking for the code cake uses to convert the find(...) into SQL. Sure there is a few errors in the grammar but OP is probably not a native English speaker. The best way to learn something is to get under the hood and see what is going on, this sort of thing should be encouraged, not shot down.

Comment: Thanks for your comment dogmatic69! As you guessed im not a native English speaker and i guess its easy to tell sometimes. Your right about digging into stuff aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it, its in \lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php in the function read()

Comment: DboSource is correct, I just hope you are using this for debugging and not hacking the core as you can make modifications without changing the core code ;). Don't forget to mark this as correct when you can.

Comment: I was just using this for debugging, and it solved my problem quick after finding it =) Thanks!